# get div class by content inside div using C#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I need to identify the class of a `div` element which contains some text. 
For example I have this HTML page

```html
<html>
    ...
    <div class='x'>
        <p>this is the text I have.</p>
        <p>Another part of text.</p>
    </div>
    ...
</html>
```

So I know the text `this is the text I have. Another part of text.` And I need to identify the div class name. Is there an way to do this using C#?

Comment: Is it a asp.net or mvc ?

Comment: Are you following ASP.NET or ASP.NET with MVC?

Comment: @Gaurav Singh Jantwal it is just an html code. I have many pages from different websites (with different html structure) and I need identify the "html bourders" of articles text for each. After tat I will use HTML AGILITY PACK to get the innerText from each page.

Comment: You  can read the HTML page as XML document, then, using HTML agility you can check using `selector` or iterating etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the answer of diiN_. This is a bit verbose but you should be able to get what you need from it. The code depends on the [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). You can get it using nuget.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("<html>");
sb.AppendFormat("<div class='x'>");
sb.AppendFormat("<p>this is the text I have.</p>");
sb.AppendFormat("<p>Another part of text.</p>");
sb.AppendFormat("</div>");
sb.AppendFormat("</html>");

const string stringToSearch = "<p>this is the text I have.</p><p>Another part of text.</p>";

var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(sb.ToString());

var divsWithText = document
    .DocumentNode
    .Descendants("div")
    .Where(node => node.Descendants()
                       .Any(des => des.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text))
    .ToList();

var divsWithInnerHtmlMatching =
    divsWithText
        .Where(div => div.InnerHtml.Equals(stringToSearch))
        .ToList();

var innerHtmlAndClass =
    divsWithInnerHtmlMatching
        .Select(div => 
            new
            {
                InnerHtml = div.InnerHtml,
                Class = div.Attributes["class"].Value
            });

foreach (var item in innerHtmlAndClass)
{
Console.WriteLine("class='{0}' innerHtml='{1}'", item.Class, item.InnerHtml);
}
```

Comment: What if adding a library to the solution is not an option? Should we go towards dirty text processing ways?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string stringToSearch = "<p>this is the text I have.</p><p>Another part of text.</p>";
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(sb.ToString());

var classOfDiv = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Select(x => new
{
    ClassOfDiv = x.Attributes["class"].Value
}).Where(x => x.InnerHtml = stringToSearch);
```

The variable `classOfDiv` now contains the `class` name of the desired `div`.

Comment: Thank you. But there is no IntterText property for x. How could it be fixed?

Comment: there is just no property InnerHtml or InnerText for x... I added HtmlAgilityPack to project. So this is not the problem

Comment: Hey, just enough rep to comment - the problem is the ".Select". it's creating a new sequence of anonymous variables, each of which has a "ClassOfDiv" property, but the rest of the information that was contained in the div nodes (the 'x' variable inside the select) is being discarded.

Comment: @Donal Now I understood. Thank you