# Linq query selects values from first row only in table

Tags: c#, linq, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to parse website table to List using Linq.

Here is the source code:

```html
<div id="users_table" class="security_slick_container slickgrid_300610 ui-widget" style="overflow: hidden; outline: 0px; position: relative;">
    <div tabindex="0" hidefocus="" style="position:fixed;width:0;height:0;top:0;left:0;outline:0;"></div>
    <div class="slick-header ui-state-default" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
        <div class="slick-header-columns" style="left: -1000px; width: 2132px;" unselectable="on">
            <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column slick-header-sortable slick-header-column-sorted" id="slickgrid_300610userName" title="" style="width: 94px;"><span class="slick-column-name"><strong>Username:</strong></span><span class="slick-sort-indicator slick-sort-indicator-asc"></span>
                <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column slick-header-sortable" id="slickgrid_300610firstName" title="" style="width: 89px;"><span class="slick-column-name"><strong>Firstname:</strong></span><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
                <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column slick-header-sortable" id="slickgrid_300610lastName" title="" style="width: 109px;"><span class="slick-column-name"><strong>Lastname:</strong></span><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
                <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column slick-header-sortable" id="slickgrid_300610type" title="" style="width: 124px;"><span class="slick-column-name"><strong>Type:</strong></span><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
                <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column slick-header-sortable" id="slickgrid_300610crew" title="" style="width: 109px;"><span class="slick-column-name"><strong>Crew:</strong></span><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
                <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column slick-header-sortable" id="slickgrid_300610jobTitle" title="" style="width: 109px;"><span class="slick-column-name"><strong>Job title:</strong></span><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
                <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column slick-header-sortable" id="slickgrid_300610defaultPriceClass" title="" style="width: 124px;"><span class="slick-column-name"><strong>Defaultprice class:</strong></span><span class="slick-sort-indicator"></span>
                <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_300610description" title="" style="width: 129px;"><span class="slick-column-name"><strong>Description:</strong></span>
                <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-state-default slick-header-column" id="slickgrid_300610language" title="" style="width: 39px;"><span class="slick-column-name"><strong>Language:</strong></span>
                <div class="slick-resizable-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-headerrow ui-state-default" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: none;">
        <div class="slick-headerrow-columns" style="width: 1115px;"></div>
        <div style="display: block; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1132px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-top-panel-scroller ui-state-default" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: none;">
        <div class="slick-top-panel" style="width:10000px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; outline: 0px; position: relative; height: 567px;">
        <div class="grid-canvas" style="height: 16550px; width: 1115px;">
            <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px">
                <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">john.smith</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">John</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">Smith</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">Contractor</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l4 r4">Microsoft</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l5 r5">Sales manager</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l6 r6">A</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l7 r7"></div>
                <div class="slick-cell l8 r8">en</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:25px">
                <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">robert.geits</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">Robert</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">Geits</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">Staff</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l4 r4">Google</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l5 r5">Project manager</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l6 r6">B</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l7 r7"></div>
                <div class="slick-cell l8 r8">de</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:50px">
                <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">amir.rooney</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">Amir</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">Rooney</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">Staff</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l4 r4">Microsoft</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l5 r5">Sales manager</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l6 r6">A</div>
                <div class="slick-cell l7 r7"></div>
                <div class="slick-cell l8 r8">en</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="0" hidefocus="" style="position:fixed;width:0;height:0;top:0;left:0;outline:0;"></div>
</div>
```

What is the right Linq query to perform such an operation? My current Linq query selects only first row from table for some reason?

Here is my current code:

```
var DataHere = from cells in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]")) //.FindElements(By.TagName("div"))
               select new
               {
                   Username = cells.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l0 r0')]")).Text,
                   Firstname = cells.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l1 r1')]")).Text,
                   Lastname = cells.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l2 r2')]")).Text,
                   Type = cells.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l3 r3')]")).Text,
                   Crew = cells.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l4 r4')]")).Text,
                   JobTitle = cells.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l5 r5')]")).Text,
                   DefaultPrice = cells.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l6 r6')]")).Text,
                   Future = cells.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l7 r7')]")).Text,
                   Language = cells.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l8 r8')]")).Text,
               };
```

I am checking values in List using this line:

```
DataHere.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));
```

Comment: I would bet to the cells.FindElement(By.XPath...) being the problem. I think the parsing from divs list to your object is not being done properly, but cant say anything further.

Comment: I think this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271768/get-div-class-by-content-inside-div-using-c-sharp anycase I do agree with @bmartins

Comment: Problem is that I need to Login to page before parsing. I am not sure HtmlAgilityPack can do such a trick. It can't be probably combined Selenium + HtmlAgilityPack as how HtmlAgilityPack will know that current windows is where it should take an information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you expect each element returned by `driver.FindElements(...)` to be a `<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row ...">` element. A simple CSS selector should do the trick:

```
var rows = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#users_table .slick-viewport .slick-row"));
```

The LINQ statement would look like:

```
var DataHere = from row in driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#users_table .slick-viewport .slick-row"))
               select new
               {
                   ...
               };
```

Within each row you need to find "cells" which seem to be `<div class="slick-cell">`. Your xpaths all begin with `//` to find each cell. Those xpaths will be evaluated globally — it will search the *entire* web page. You want to scope the xpaths to each row. Instead of:

```
rows.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l0 r0')]"))
```

You want to prefix each xpath with a `.` character:

```
      row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l0 r0')]"))
                                ^
                                |
This becomes relative xpath ----+
```

The `.` character means Selenium will search within the current `row` object, which is what you want in this case. If you don't, Selenium returns the very first element in the entire web page that matches the XPath expression.

I would also recommend creating a proper [page object model](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models/) representing each row:

```
public class UserTableRow
{
    private readonly IWebElement row;

    public string Username => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l0 r0')]")).Text,
    public string Firstname => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l1 r1')]")).Text,
    public string Lastname => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l2 r2')]")).Text,
    public string Type => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l3 r3')]")).Text,
    public string Crew => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l4 r4')]")).Text,
    public string JobTitle => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l5 r5')]")).Text,
    public string DefaultPrice => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l6 r6')]")).Text,
    public string Future => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l7 r7')]")).Text,
    public string Language => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l8 r8')]")).Text,

    public UserTableRow(IWebElement row)
    {
        this.row = row;
    }
}
```

This will really clean up your LINQ statement:

```
var DataHere = from row in driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#users_table .slick-viewport .slick-row"))
               select new UserTableRow(row);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Can you give your point of view why table is not parsed completely? I have noticed the same behavior also with previous attempts. It gets all names starting on A and partly on B, but does not proceed forwards. No errors displayed. There does not seem to be any changes in code for table. Is there something to be done with Async/Await?

Comment: I just went for more detailed investigations and noticed that table gets loaded with values on a scroll. So on a scroll it's values are changing in source code. Is there any chance to parse such a case?

Comment: @hatman: Yes. You need to scroll down, and as you scroll get the "rows" again. This will be more difficult, though. It is worth posting a new question after you have tried a few things out.

Comment: I am just thinking out loud... it should scroll down and compare what is already in the list, then add values only that are not in the list? So basically add, scroll, compare, add etc? P.S. Haven't used to deal with such a beauty before.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your call `driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]"))` will get element(s) with id="users_table". Looks like there is only one of those, your top-level "table" `<div>`. So, your "cells" is not actually a collection of cells, it's just your single top-level "table" `<div>`.