# Repeat linq query several times

Tags: c#, linq, selenium

This question is related to previous question
[Linq query selects values from first row only in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110856/linq-query-selects-values-from-first-row-only-in-table)

I am trying to get this code working. My intention is to add visible items from web table to object using Linq query. Web table is loaded dynamically so while scrolling it is loaded with items and other items are unloaded at the same time. Scrolling down directly after loading page is not an option.

I have several questions:

1. Can Linq query be done this way (add visible items, scroll, add visible items etc.)
2. How to convert `DataHereH` to List `DataHere`?

Here is my current code:

```
    public static IEnumerable<UserTableRow> AddItemsToList(IWebDriver driver)
    {

        IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rows = new List<IWebElement>();

        object DataHereH;

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]/div[5]/div/div[1]")).Click();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            rows = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#users_table .slick-viewport .slick-row"));

            // This part will get our first visible items in table to list, after page load 
            DataHereH = from row in rows
                        select new UserTableRow(row);

            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown).Build().Perform();
        }

        List<UserTableRow> noDupes = DataHere.Distinct().ToList();

        return noDupes;
    }
```

Here are parameters:

```
   public class UserTableRow
    {
        private readonly IWebElement row;

        public string Username => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l0 r0')]")).Text;
        public string Firstname => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l1 r1')]")).Text;
        public string Lastname => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l2 r2')]")).Text;
        public string Type => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l3 r3')]")).Text;
        public string Crew => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l4 r4')]")).Text;
        public string JobTitle => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l5 r5')]")).Text;
        public string DefaultPrice => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l6 r6')]")).Text;
        public string Future => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l7 r7')]")).Text;
        public string Language => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l8 r8')]")).Text;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "SharePrice: " + Username.ToString() + ": " + Firstname.ToString();
        }

        public UserTableRow(IWebElement row)
        {
            try
            {
                this.row = row;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the HTML for the table?

Comment: @GregBurghardt it is still the same table from this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110856/linq-query-selects-values-from-first-row-only-in-table

Comment: That's good, but your current question should contain everything people need to answer it, without hunting around in previous questions.

Comment: @GregBurghardt question edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator for this.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<UserTableRow> AddItemsToList(IWebDriver driver)
{
    var uniqueData = new HashSet<UserTableRow>();
    var actions = new Actions(driver);

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]/div[5]/div/div[1]")).Click();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        var latestElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#users_table .slick-viewport .slick-row"));
        foreach (var element in latestElements)
        {
            var row = new UserTableRow(element);
            var isUnique = uniqueData.Add(row);
            if (isUnique) yield return row;
        }
        actions.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown).Build().Perform();
    }
}
```

**But be aware**, in both this case and the case of Linq's `Distinct` you need to provide an object that uses value equality.

Currently your `UserTableRow` class uses reference equality, so you will receive duplicates.

To mitigate this you can do one of the following:

- Implement value comparison: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type
- If the selenium driver uses value equality or if it has some internal caching, you can change the hashset to track unique `IWebElement`'s.

### Example

If you copy the base class from the following guide from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects

```cs
public abstract class ValueObject
{
    protected static bool EqualOperator(ValueObject left, ValueObject right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null) ^ ReferenceEquals(right, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return ReferenceEquals(left, null) || left.Equals(right);
    }

    protected static bool NotEqualOperator(ValueObject left, ValueObject right)
    {
        return !(EqualOperator(left, right));
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        ValueObject other = (ValueObject)obj;
        IEnumerator<object> thisValues = GetAtomicValues().GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<object> otherValues = other.GetAtomicValues().GetEnumerator();
        while (thisValues.MoveNext() && otherValues.MoveNext())
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(thisValues.Current, null) ^
                ReferenceEquals(otherValues.Current, null))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (thisValues.Current != null &&
                !thisValues.Current.Equals(otherValues.Current))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return !thisValues.MoveNext() && !otherValues.MoveNext();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetAtomicValues()
         .Select(x => x != null ? x.GetHashCode() : 0)
         .Aggregate((x, y) => x ^ y);
    }
    // Other utility methods
}
```

Then you can redefine `UserTableRow` as follows:

```cs
public class UserTableRow : ValueObject
{
    public string Username { get; private set; }
    public string Firstname{ get; private set; }
    public string Lastname { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }
    public string Crew { get; private set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; private set; }
    public string DefaultPrice { get; private set; }
    public string Future { get; private set; }
    public string Language { get; private set; }

    public UserTableRow(IWebElement row)
    {
        Username = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l0 r0')]")).Text;
        Firstname = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l1 r1')]")).Text;
        LastName = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l2 r2')]")).Text;
        Type = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l3 r3')]")).Text;
        Crew = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l4 r4')]")).Text;
        JobTitle = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l5 r5')]")).Text;
        DefaultPrice = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l6 r6')]")).Text;
        Future = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l7 r7')]")).Text;
        Language =row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l8 r8')]")).Text;
    }
    
    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
    {
        yield return Username;
        yield return Firstname;
        yield return LastName;
        yield return Type;
        yield return Crew;
        yield return JobTitle;
        yield return DefaultPrice;
        yield return Future;
        yield return Language;
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of implementing value equality, so you will be able to use the hashset to remove duplicates. But it has the disadvantage of removing the ability to interact with the elements as this will provide a shapshot of the dom at construction time.

Note: This type of thing will be much easier with C# 9 - See records https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/

Comment: Thank you for this! It works but not completely, after some scrolling down it catches an error pointing at `public string Username => row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l0 r0')]")).Text;`. Any ideas how to avoid that? This element is still there, but is there some reason code is not able to find it? Does it match with scrolling execution time producing an error?

Comment: I have limited experience with Selenium, but I would imagine this is because its storing a reference to the DOM and it may not be loaded after the scrolling. To mitigate this, you can store the information when creating the UserTableRow class. So instead of using Get only properties, evaluating the values in the constructor:

Comment: public UserTableRow(IWebElement row)
        {
          Username  = row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class, 'slick-cell l0 r0')]")).Text;
        }

Comment: Thank you again! Seems correct. I think now I have only get in my constructor as it says `Property or indexer cannot be assigned to "--" it is read only` pointing at Username. I am on my learning curve still. Just trying to make something useful to understand how it works. Is it possible to update to your answer example of constructor with what you mentioned earlier to understand how properties should be set?

Comment: I added an example with an altered `UserTableRow`